# Is there someway to make distributed table still work for query when one of the shard servers down?

Tags: clickhouse

There is a common case that we will update the clickhouse's config which must restart clickhouse to take effect. And during the restarting, the query services depend on clickhouse's distributed table will return the exception due to disconnecting with the restarting server.

So,as the title says, what I want is the way to make distributed table still work for query when one of the shard server down. Thanks.

Comment: Just clarify, the problem is you send a request to a restarted server? Or restarting any server leads to failure of a distributed table? Answer on the first question see below. About the second question - it looks like you didn't configure replication - could you provide the cluster config to check it?

Comment: @vladimirG Actually, it's the second question. Yes, replication of cluster should be the best way to solve this problem.But in my case, I have a replicated table **A** and ten of non-replicated tables **Bs** generated from **A** using materialized view, all the queries are sent to **Bs** now. Distributed table will  still not work when restarting, unless I convert *Bs* to replicated table, and the conversion of ten tables in ten servers  is a heavy work according to the ck documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways:

1. Since this server failure is transient, you can refactor your server-side code by adding retry-policy to your request (for c# I would recommend use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly))
2. Use the proxy (load-balancer) to CH (for example [chproxy](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/third-party/proxy/)).

**UPDATE**

When one node is restarting in a cluster the distributed table created over replicated tables should be accessible (of course request shouldn't be sent to restarted node).

Availability of data is achieved by using replication, therefore, you need to create Replicated*-tables over materialized view and then create Distributed-tables over Replicated*-tables.

Please look at the articles [CH Data Distribution](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2017/6/5/clickhouse-data-distribution), [Distributed vs Shard vs Replicated..](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2161)
and as a working example (*it is not your case*) to [CH Circular cluster topology](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/5/10/circular-replication-cluster-topology-in-clickhouse).

Comment: Yes, they does work for sending request to a single server. But for distributed table they doesn't. By the way, restart a server with massive data will take a long time, almost ten minutes or more, that's why I want to find a elegant way to make users feelless. Thanks

Comment: Are you restart a server or clickhouse-service? Restarting service is enough and takes a little time - _sudo service clickhouse-server restart_. Nevertheless, reboot that takes several minutes looks pretty suspicious - I would try to investigate this issue.

Comment: I was definitely restarting the clickhouse service using `service clickhouse-server restart`. There is a [issue](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2278) that  discusses this question.